# How can I only do a preventDefault on certain keys in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have this code in Blazor:

```
<input @bind-value="@textBoxValue" @onkeydown="@OnKeyDown" @onkeydown:preventDefault>
```

Now every key that is pressed will trigger this event, and by adding the 'preventDefault' I make sure that certain keys can't be used in certain situations.

For example, the OnKeyDown method will check if a key is numeric or is a Backspace to remove the latest character:

```
private void OnKeyDown (KeyboardEventArgs e) 
{
   Enums.KeyCode key = Enums.GetKeyType(e.Code); //Own defined enum containing keycodes

   if(key == Enums.KeyCode.Backspace) 
   {
      //Remove latest key
      if (textBoxValue.Length >= 1) {
      textBoxValue= textBoxValue.Substring(0, textBoxValue.Length - 1);
   } 
   else 
   {
      //Do other stuff, like checking for numeric input only
   }
}
```

The problem is: I want some keys to act normally, like the 'Tab' key to focus the next element.

Inside the  KeyEventArgs function from System.Windows.Forms, you can set the event handler to Handled, by using.

`e.Handled = true;`

In Forms you can also just use return to stop the current event.

Is there a way I can implement this using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web **KeyboardEventArgs**?

Comment: No, because of Blazor Server, where the event has to happen asynchronously, there is no way to conditionally preventDefault from C#. This is one of those occasions where you will find it easiest resort to a little javascript.

Comment: So its actually better to just remove preventDefault? The problem I have, is that I want to check the input (I can do it with @oninput), and then change the binded value. But then you see for a split second the value before it changes back to the new checked one set in the @oninput event.